# Reading and updating complex JSON Object in power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, power-automate, json-formatting

We have a requirement to update the content in the JSON Stored as multiline text column in one of the list, when one of the item in the another list is updated we need to update the JSON data stored in the item of the source list.

here is the sample json

```
    [
{
ClientStoryId:
ClientStoryName:
AssetID:
AssetName:
UserName:
UserEmail:
UserID:
}
{
ClientStoryId:
ClientStoryName:
AssetID:
AssetName:
UserName:
UserEmail:
UserID:
}
{
ClientStoryId:
ClientStoryName:
AssetID:
AssetName:
UserName:
UserEmail:
UserID:
}
]
```

When a user gets added to the Users List with client story and assetName we need to appropriately update the userdetails in the JSON which will be stored as multiline of text in another list.

Kindly help me.

Comment: In the **destination** JSON list, are you storing all the users' details in a single item (combined into a single JSON) or  storing each user's details in its own item (each user in separate JSON)?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the screenshots and explanation below.
In the example, the source list is **UserStory** and the destination list is **UserStoryJSON**, which is linked with the source list [ID] on [UserStoryId]

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]

### Detail 3

[image]

### Expressions 1 & 2

```
length(outputs('Get_items_-_UserStoryJSON_List')?['body/value'])

first(outputs('Get_items_-_UserStoryJSON_List')?['body/value'])?['ID']
```

### Output of Source and Destination Lists

[image]

[image]